# Issues getting file extensions using os.path.splitext() method

Tags: python, pathlib

I am working on a Flask blog application, and I am trying to separate a file extension from a filename. For example, for the filename "IMG_0503.jpg," I would like to get "IMG_0503" and ".jpg" separately. I tried the pathlib module and the os.path.splitext() method, but both return an empty file extension instead of ".jpg"

Here is my code with os.path.splitext():

```
uploaded_file = request.files['file']
print("UPLOADED_FILE:", uploaded_file)
filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
print("FILENAME:", filename)

filename = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
print("OS.PATH.SPLITEXT:", os.path.splitext(filename))
print("FILE_EXT:", file_ext)
```

This is the output of print statements:

```
UPLOADED_FILE: <FileStorage: 'IMG_0503.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
FILENAME: IMG_0503.jpg
OS.PATH.SPLITEXT: ('IMG_0503', '')
FILE_EXT:
```

With the pathlib, the output is exactly the same, but I am using `file_ext = pathlib.Path(filename).suffix`  to get the extension.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution:

```
import pathlib


# function to return the file extension
file_extension = pathlib.Path('my_file.txt').suffix
print("File Extension: ", file_extension)
```

Output:

File Extension:  .txt

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out that os.path.splitext() was not working because I assigned the return value of os.path.splitext(filename)[0] to the variable called filename.